# How to edit the SQL string in pgAdmin's "Last 100 Rows" window?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

pgAdmin allows us to view last/first 100 rows by mouse right click menu. Is there any way to edit the SQL string?

See picture below:

[image: pgAdmin View/Edit Data window]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The manual:](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/query_tool_toolbar.html#query-tool-toolbar)

> The [Query Tool](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/query_tool.html#query-tool) and [View/Edit Data](https://www.pgadmin.org/docs/pgadmin4/latest/editgrid.html#editgrid) tools are actually
> different operating modes of the same tool. Some controls will be
> disabled in either mode.

In the "View/Edit Data" window you can only "edit" the query string with the "Filter" and "Limit Selector" buttons in the tool bar.

To truly edit, copy the query string, open a "Query Tool" in the main browser (or use the button "New query tool for current connection" at the top), and paste. In a "Query Tool" window you can edit freely.

Comment: got it, thanks a lot, the key is : copy and paste SQL  ^_^

Comment: Disappointing that PgAdmin does not allow modification of the existing query in the view/edit data pane. A standard feature in many other SQL editors.